# Raspberry Pi3 Retropie : .lutro files for Mame2003 libretro aren't working

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3

**Hello everybody!**

I'm currently trying to launch **.lutro** files (ROMs for **Mame2003 Libretro**). Unfortunately it doesn't work, here's what happens when the ROM is launched :

*1-* ROM seems at first to launch normally

*2-* The screen goes black for about 1 second

*3-* And we go back to the menu where Mame2003 Libretro games are

What is the most annoying thing about this issue is that **my final goal isn't even to simply launch a .lutro ROM** but a game developped by classmates... But first I need to solve this problem.

I saw a [forum](https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/16835/solved-some-mame2003-games-stopped-working) online talking about something called "*Rewind*". Apparently the issue would be related to the game who would be unable to have "*savestates*" and in order to solve that, we would apparently need to delete a file called *nvram*.

And here we stumble against another issue... The *nvram* file maybe is (I still haven't checked) inside the offical .lutro ROMs. But I can assure all of you that there is no *nvram* files inside the game developped by my classmates, and our game has exactly the same issue as the official .lutro ROMs. So here we go back to the beginning. Maybe the issue is directly in Retropie. Maybe not. I really do not have any way to know that.

That's why I hope that someone who reads this stumbled into the same issue and found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

.lutro files are meant to be launched with libretro-lutro which is a love2d-like game engine, not MAME2003.